# New app in Google Play with same name but different package name

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I want to upload another apk with the same application title as one I already have (which has been unpublished). I receive:

> You need to choose a different title for your app. This one is already
>   the title of com.foo.bar.

I thought I would be able to upload the new apk as long as the package name was different. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to create another Google Play Developer account?

Comment: Why would you have different things named the same in the first place?

Comment: @ligi The first one is an alpha. I have completely rewritten the app for production. The original has been unpublished so does not appear in Google Play. Only a handful of alpha testers have it installed.

Comment: Just rename the unpublished one - no need for a new account then - but better use the alpha/beta feature of google-play for this

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could rename apps. Create an answer and I will accept.

Comment: you are welcome - added the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can rename the old app - after this you are able to create a new app with this name. No need for a second account

Comment: I have done the same thing but, I got message from Google saying my application has been suspended cause it strikes impersonation policy.

Comment: I did in that way but currently I'm unable to search and find it in google play market with name