# Is it possible to have 2 same Android app

Tags: android, google-play

My application was suspended in Google Play. I have published a new application in Google Play with this same name, but another package name. Does Google allow to publish second application with the same name and logo from one developer?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724141/new-app-in-google-play-with-same-name-but-different-package-name

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can publish application with the same display name but the package name should be different. To avoid confusion better go with different Display Name.
for example : Example App v2

Answer (score 1):

yes you can upload multiple apps but with different package name